# UITableView with button in each cell highlights many cells when one is long pressed

Tags: ios, uitableview

We are using a UITableView to represent a list of objects. The user can select to press a button in a cell to perform an action on an object. The tableview can grow while the user is interacting with it. The user can perform the action with a "touch up inside" on the button.
What we see is that "random" buttons can sometimes get highlighted if I long-press a button.
So some cell-buttons, if I long-press them, they themselves get highlighted. Everything looks OK. But some, if I long-press them, then some other cells get highlighted quickly sequentially. So for example:

- Long press button on cell # 5
- Cell #5 gets highlighted for a short while.
- Cell #2 gets highlighted for a short while, then cell #3 gets highlighted for a short while etc..
- This can go on forever, the highlighting just jumps from button to button.

What determines if a cell gets highlighted? The button is in custom cell view and has "Highlighted Adjusts Image" which I assume causes the visual effect in the first place.

More interestingly is that I don't see any callbacks to didHightlightRowAtIndex. The buttons sometimes just get highlighted in a "flickering way" and I cannot figure out why and how to fix it.

Comment: Perhaps you've forgotten that cells are reused? But really, with no code at all, the question is unanswerable. If you want help, take the time to create and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

How you are handling the highlighted cell, on long press??
You can follow the step to achieve the required functionality.

Step 1: Add isHighlighted key in your array of model.
for ex.

```
let array = [SomeModel1, SomeModel2]

DomeModel{
  "name" : "ABC", 
  "id" : 123,
  "isHighlighted" : false
}
```

Step 2: Display highlighted cell, on the behalf of "isHighlighted"

Step 3: On long press of any cell, If you want to show the highlighted mode of cell, change the "isHighlighted" value on the index.

for ex:

let array = [SomeModel1, SomeModel2]

```
DomeModel1{
  "name" : "ABC", 
  "id" : 123,
  "isHighlighted" : false
}

DomeModel2{
  "name" : "ABC", 
  "id" : 123,
  "isHighlighted" : false
}
```

long press on cell index 1, update the value

```
array[index].isHighlighted = true,
reloadTheRow()
```

Hopefully it will solve your problem.